# Is the phrase "want to be do" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

[From a post](http://nicolejessicacoggan.com/how-i-finally-worked-out-what-i-wanted-to-do-with-my-life/)

> Although I’ve never had a problem finding work (even if it was in a factory or shearing sheds),   I do know what a struggle it can be to work out what you actually **want to be do**, or worse, when you get so far down a certain path and then realise it’s not for you.

"to do" is the basic form of a verb. Although the quotation uses the pattern "want to be do". Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense. It is presumably a mistake: either for _want to be **or** do_, or the writer decided to change _be_ to _do_, or the other way round, and left both of them in.

Comment: Possibly "or" was inadvertently omitted between "be" and "do."